# Trying to use v-for with v-if in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a array of photos, and i need, before loading page, change SRC of image.

Example:

```
images: [
   { name: 'Car', image: require('../assets/car.png') },
   { name: 'Book', image: require('../assets/book.png') },
]
```

And my template code:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in images" :key=index>
   <div v-if="item.name=="selectedItem"
     <img :src="item.image" width="100px" height="auto">
   </div>
</div>
```

Script code:

```
created() {
  switch (selectedItem){
    case 'car':
        Change SRC to  ../assets/car.png    
      break;
    case 'book':
      Change SRC to  ../assets/book.png   
      break;
}
```

How i can do this?

When i trying this, i get selectedItem is undefined on render

Answer (score 0):

You should use a function to return what you want. Something like:

```
<div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key=index>
 <div v-if="selectedSrc.length"
  <img :src="getSelectedSrc(image.name)" width="100px" height="auto">
 </div>
</div>
```

Note that, to check selectedSrc length in this case, is irrelevant, since you are running a loop inside an array that will always have a filtered result.

Inside your Vue declarations:

```
data() {
 return {
  images: [
   { name: 'Car', image: '../assets/car.png' },
   { name: 'Book', image: '../assets/book.png' },
  ],
  selectedSrc: [],
 };
},
methods: {
 getSelectedSrc(name) {
  this.selectedSrc = this.images.filter(item => item.name === name);
  return this.selectedSrc[0].image;
 },
}
```

If you have more than one result inside the filtered selectedSrc array, you will get just the first result. Considering your images array being not a dynamic array, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Vue style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential), avoid using `v-if` with `v-for` is essential.

Your code above can be refactored by prefilter the data with `computed` property, **make the `template` for purely displaying data**. I guess `selectedItem` is passed as `props`? then here is the code:

```
<div v-if="selected">
 <img :src="selected.image" width="100px" height="auto">
</div>

props: { selectedItem },
data() {
 return {
  images: [
   { name: 'Car', image: '../assets/car.png' },
   { name: 'Book', image: '../assets/book.png' },
  ]
 };
},
computed: {
 selected() {
  return this.images.find(img => img.name == selectedItem);
 }
}
```